# How to access json object value by key in View Angular 6

Tags: angular

I'm new to Angular 6. I'm not getting how to access Json object values in view using key.

I'm making http.get(url) in my service and I'm calling that method in my component

```
export class CustomersComponent implements OnInit {

constructor(private accounts: AccountService) { }
account: Object;

ngOnInit() {
  this.accounts.getAccountById(1).subscribe((data)=> {
  this.account = data ;
}
);}}
```

The returned data is a json object is like this

```
{
 "accountId": 1,
 "attributeCode": "2300000000",
 "attributeLabel": "Customer Status"
 }
```

How to access the values inside this json object in view?

I have tried using

```
{{account.accountId}}
```

getting error in console as accountId undefined

```
   {{account | json}}
```

This is working fine, it is printing everything but I would like to use the values inside this object at different places in my view.

Answer (score 1):

Access using **`[key]`** as follows,

```
{{account['accountId']}}
```

Comment: Getting this error. TypeError: Cannot read property 'undefined' of undefined

Comment: you should enclose in quotes as its a string

Answer (score 0):

To access values of correspondent key, do like this

```
{{account['accountId']}}
```

because `accountId` or key is string.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe It's because your data is not loaded yet. I suggest put an `div` or `ng-template` before accessing it in template and if account is provided, then try to access it.like below:

```
<div *ngIf="account">
{{account['accountId']}}
</div>
```

or this:

```
{{account?.accountId}}
```